# Uploading to iTunesConnect with Organiser crashes

Tags: iphone, xcode, crash, app-store-connect, organizer

I've been trying to re-upload a previously uploaded app (it originally failed submission), but both the 'Validate' and the 'Submit' button in Organiser crash Organiser itself before finishing. This has been happening for about three days now, and I haven't heard a word back from the iTunesConnect helpdesk. I am running the lastest Xcode 3.2.5 with iOS 4.2.1, and downloaded and installed the latest Application Tools as instructed. Everything installed fine.

I'm getting a:

[image]

with:

> ```
> Process:         Xcode [32144]
> Path:            /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
> Identifier:      com.apple.Xcode
> Version:         3.2.5 (1760)
> Build Info:      DevToolsIDE-17600000~5
> Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
> Parent Process:  launchd [348]
>
> Date/Time:       2010-12-03 17:29:50.499 +1000
> OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.5 (10H574)
> Report Version:  6
>
> Interval Since Last Report:          4332 sec
> Crashes Since Last Report:           2
> Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  1215 sec
> Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   2
>
> Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
> Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
> Crashed Thread:  7  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority
>
> Application Specific Information:
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ITunesSoftwareApplicationDescription applicationType]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x200c57ae0'
> *** Call stack at first throw:
> (
>     0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff840087b4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
>     1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff886ea0f3 objc_exception_throw + 45
>     2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff84062110 +[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 0
>     3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff83fda91f ___forwarding___ + 751
> ```

I know that this isn't the place to debug Apple apps - but someone must have had this happen and figured out how to get past it? I'm getting no joy from apple :(

thanks

Comment: Have you try delete the previous version and install again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a work around, you could try Application Loader.app in /Developer/Applications/Utilities.

I generally find this more reliable.

Comment: You're right - it's a work around, and takes a bit more effort, but that did the trick :)

Answer (score 2):

You should create an .ipa file for you App and then use application loader as Andrew said.
Worked for me.

Btw nobody can get joy from a computer company ;) ... Apple or any other...

Answer (score 0):

Check what version of Xcode you're running. I had a similar issue where I was running a developer preview - you can't submit an app from a DP version of Xcode, and mine was crashing at the exact same point as yours.

Hope this helps.